# Skipping a word after comma in char array

Tags: c++

I need to skip a word after a comma in char array. My code is next:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    char r1[] = "Hello, listen to me. I want to ask, if you.";
    char del[] = ", ";
    int k = strlen(r1);
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= k) {
        if (r1[i] == del[0]) {//Checking if there is a comma
            i++;
            if (r1[i] == del[1]) {//Checking if there is a space after co
                while (r1[i] != del[1]) {//Looking for a next space to skip a word
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
        else {//If no comma, just type a letter
            std::cout << r1[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. I want to have an answer like: "Hello, to me. I want to ask, you." So it just should skip word after comma, not including space.

This code gives me just a code without commas: "Hello listen to me. I want to ask if you."

P.S. I need to do this as basic as i can because i am a beginner.

Comment: Recommendation: Run the code in a debugger and step through it line by line. Watch exactly what the program does, the values it stores and the path it takes, and you'll learn a lot more and a lot faster than simply being fed a solution. Using a debugger is a vital skill to the working programmer and probably the only reason I managed to find the time to run my Champions campaigns while a student. The sooner you get a good grip on using the debugger, the sooner you can reap the rewards.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in `while (r1[i] != del[1])` is always false right after the condition `if (r1[i] == del[1])`. You forgot `++i` between them.

If you fix it, you get the next possible issue - spaces after commas are not printed.

Comment: You are right but now is just stops after Hello. Where should i put the second while or while loop is not the best option to use here?

Comment: It works well after the fix, does not stop after "Hello"
https://ideone.com/IfDUEm

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
    char r1[] = "Hello, listen to me. I want to ask, if you. ,sda";
    char del[] = ", ";
    int k = strlen(r1);
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= k) {
        if (r1[i] == del[0]) {//Checking if there is a comma
            std::cout << r1[i];
            ++i;
            
            if (r1[i] == del[1] || r1[i] != del[1]) {//Checking if there is a space after comma
                ++i;
                while (r1[i] != del[1]) {//Looking for a next space to skip a word
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
        else {//If no comma, just type a letter
            std::cout << r1[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works. "Hello, to me. I want to ask, if you. ," - output